# THREE.subdivisionModifier and texture mapping issue seems to give incorrect results

Tags: javascript, three.js

Following example of subdivision modifier on 
https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Subdivision-Cube.html
I have tested this code with latest downloadable threejs build and it still has same issue

[image]

These spikes should actually be cube with smoothing applied! Subdivision modifier seems to spoil the cube faces
Thanks for Help.

Comment: See the working three.js [example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_subdivision.html). What seems to be the problem?

Comment: The above example works fine, minute you change material map to texture, everything explodes

Comment: In the source code file `SubdivisionModifier.js` it states: "Known Issues: currently doesn't handle UVs".

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, any other possibilities to achieve similar results ?

Comment: Maybe you can study the code and fix the problem?